# What does I_n_test = I_N mean inside of the for loop?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, syntax

I am trying to understand the code here: http://devernay.free.fr/vision/src/prosac.c

Mainly because I want to translate it into python.

Here is a snippet:

```
for(n_test = N, I_n_test = I_N; n_test > m; n_test--) { 
  // Loop invariants:
  // - I_n_test is the number of inliers for the n_test first correspondences
  // - n_best is the value between n_test+1 and N that maximizes the ratio                       
  I_n_best/n_best
  assert(n_test >= I_n_test);
  ...
  ...
  // prepare for next loop iteration
  I_n_test -= isInlier[n_test-1];
} // for(n_test ...
```

So what does this do `I_n_test = I_N;` in the loop statement ?

Is it a stopping condition ? Shouldn't it be `"=="` then ?

Comment: The stop condition is when `n_test > m` no longer holds.

Comment: Shouldn't the syntax then be "==" ?

Comment: @als7 No. It is an assignment. `=` is appropriate. Read the answers carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "*Is it (`I_n_test = I_N;`) a stopping condition?*"

No, it is not part of the condition.

> "*Shouldn't it be `"=="` then?*"

No,  `=` is fully appropriate.

> "*So what does this `I_n_test = I_N;` do in the loop statement?*"

`I_n_test = I_N` is just an initialization/assignment of the variable `I_n_test` as it is part of the **first** of the three sections of a `for` loop header separated by `;`.

Here is an unfolded presentation of the syntax:

```
for (
      initializations (optional)  
      ;
      condition (obliged if it shouldn't be an endless loop)  
      ;
      in- and/or decrementation (optional if the condition can be influenced 
    )                           inside the loop´s body or as side effect of 
                                the condition itself)
```

Since there are two initializations, they need to be separated by the `,` comma operator in the first section. Else it would be a syntactical error.

To find out more about the comma operator, take a look at:

[What does the comma operator , do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do)

---

Since `n_test` and `I_n_test` are both declared before the loop,

```
for (n_test = N, I_n_test = I_N; n_test > m; n_test--) { ...
```

is basically equivalent to:

```
n_test = N;
I_n_test = I_N;

for (; n_test > m; n_test--) { ...
```

But the assignments are brought into the loop header to show that the variables `n_test` and `I_n_test` have at least one of their main purposes in the context of the loop.

Comment: Oh ok now it makes sense! the last part cleared it up for me!

Answer (score 2):

You can read

```
 for(n_test = N, I_n_test = I_N; n_test > m; n_test--)
```

as

```
 for (initialization ; loop-checking condition; increment/decrement)
```

From the spec, chapter `§6.8.5.3`, `C11`

> *The statement*
>
> ```
>   for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement
> ```
>
> *behaves as follows: The expression `expression-2` is the controlling expression that is
>   evaluated before each execution of the loop body. The expression `expression-3` is
>   evaluated as a void expression after each execution of the loop body. If `clause-1` is a
>   declaration, the scope of any identifiers it declares is the remainder of the declaration and
>   the entire loop, including the other two expressions; it is reached in the order of execution
>   before the first evaluation of the controlling expression. If `clause-1` is an expression, it is
>   evaluated as a void expression before the first evaluation of the controlling expression.*

So, as per the syntax, `n_test = N, I_n_test = I_N` is the expression containing the initialization statements. They are separated by [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

Comment: but what does it do?  I_n_test = I_N, it is just an assignment ?

Comment: @als7 Yeah, that's right.

Comment: So if you put it outside the loop the effect will be the same ?

Comment: In this case, yes.

Answer (score 1):

> for(n_test = N, I_n_test = I_N; n_test > m; n_test--)

it initialize I_n_test = I_N & n_test = N and both variable must be separated by "," not with ";" .
If you separate with semicolon then compiler treated as I_n_test = I_n as a condition but not initialization even though you initialize I_n_test = I_n.
So it simply works like variable Assignment inside the loop.